# pointer to pointers, dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a character array of strings, where each string is terminated by null.

A pointer to the array is the starting address of the first string.

```
const char* p = "I\0had\0a\0little\0lamb\0";
```

How can I store the starting address of the other 4 strings?

This is the logic I have applied, but it is not working properly:

```
const char** stara(const char* p, int n) {
    const char** add=new char*[n];
    int k=0;
    add[k]=p;
    for(i=1;i<p.size()) {
        if(p[i]=='\0')
            add[++k]=&p[i+1];
    }
```

Comment: a vector of pointers - and I don't see what your question (so far as I can make it out) has to do with dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: i know that i have to create pointer,can u help me out more ,i am a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const char* p = "I\0had\0a\0little\0lamb\0";

const char* arr[5];
arr[0] = p;                            // "I"
arr[1] = arr[0] + strlen(arr[0]) + 1;  // "had"
arr[2] = arr[1] + strlen(arr[1]) + 1;  // "a"
arr[3] = arr[2] + strlen(arr[2]) + 1;  // "little"
arr[4] = arr[3] + strlen(arr[3]) + 1;  // "lamb"
```

That's fine for small strings.  But if you are trying to do this dynamically at runtime, especially if you don't know how many substrings you are going to be dealing with, then use something more like this instead:

```
#include <vector>

const char* p = "I\0had\0a\0little\0lamb\0";

std::vector<char*> vec;
while (*p)
{
    vec.push_back(const_cast<char*>(p));
    p += (strlen(p) + 1);
}

// vec[0] = "I"
// vec[1] = "had"
// vec[2] = "a"
// vec[3] = "little"
// vec[4] = "lamb"
```

That being said, based on your requirement stated in comments:

> Given a pointer p to the first element in a character array containing n strings (each terminated by '\0'), return a dynamically allocated array of the starting addresses of all n strings

You need something more like this:

```
const char** stara(const char* str)
{
    const char* p = str;
    int n = 0;
    while (*p)
    {
        ++n;
        p += (strlen(p) + 1);
    }

    const char* *arr = new const char*[n+1];

    p = str;
    n = 0;
    while (*p)
    {
        arr[n++] = p;
        p += (strlen(p) + 1);
    }

    arr[n] = NULL;

    return arr;
}
```

```
const char* *arr = stara("I\0had\0a\0little\0lamb\0");

// arr[0] = "I"
// arr[1] = "had"
// arr[2] = "a"
// arr[3] = "little"
// arr[4] = "lamb"
// arr[5] = NULL

delete[] arr;
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/0BSwtT)

Comment: thank you,what if p is variable..can you give me generalised way of doing this,using dynamic memory allocation

Comment: can you tell me the process using new operator in c++

Comment: There is no good reason to use `new[]` directly (other than for learning purposes). `std::vector` is already a dynamically sizable array. The code would be much more complex to use `new[]` directly.  And using `new` is outside the scope of your question.  If you need it, edit your question with more details about your actual requirements. Or post a new question.

Comment: Given a pointer p to the first element in a character array 
  containing n strings (each terminated by '\0'), return a
  dynamically allocated array of the starting addresses of all n strings.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask people to do your homework for you. You are expected to do your own research and write your own code first, then ask specific questions about it when needed.  As for your requirement, returning a filled `std::vector` is the best option. But, if you *must* return a raw `char**` pointer, then you need a 2-step approach: loop through the input string once to count the number of substrings in it, then allocate the `char*` array, then loop through the input string again assigning the addresses to the array. This is much easier when using STL classes instead.

Comment: yeah i understand,but can you tell me logic

Comment: i did my research,this is the logic i have applied,but it is not working properlyconst char** stara(const char* p, int n)
{
   const char** add=new char*[n];
   int k=0;
   add[k]=p;
   for(i=1;i<p.size())
   {if(p[i]=='\0')
   add[++k]=&p[i+1];
 
}

Comment: Then you should have put that in your original question to begin with.  In your `new[]` statement, you can't assign a non-const `char**` pointer to a `const char**` pointer. And `p` is a raw `char*` pointer so it doesn't have a `size()` method (`std::string` does). And your loop is never incrementing `i`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write code yourself for that. How do you know the number of strings?

Assuming you know `n` to be 4 and you want 4 pointers, then you could do:

```
const char *p0 = p;
const char *p1 = p0 + strlen(p0) + 1;
const char *p2 = p1 + strlen(p1) + 1;
const char *p3 = p2 + strlen(p2) + 1;
```